# Processing PGraphics ellipses not growing

Tags: processing, ellipse, pgraphics

I'm just trying to make circles grow and invert with blendMode(DIFFERENCE); but the radius is unchanged..

```
int radius = 15;
int radius2 = 15;

size(500, 500);

PGraphics pg = createGraphics(500, 500);
pg.beginDraw();
pg.background(255);
pg.blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
pg.fill(255);
pg.noStroke();
pg.ellipse(width/2, height/2, radius, radius);
pg.ellipse(width/2.25, height/2.25, radius2, radius2);
pg.ellipse(width/2.25, height/1.8, radius2, radius2);
pg.ellipse(width/1.8, height/2.25, radius2, radius2);
pg.ellipse(width/1.8, height/1.8, radius2, radius2);
radius++;
pg.endDraw();


background(255);
image(pg, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting

> If your code has methods (it's not just in static mode) or needs to run over time, it must have a draw() method, otherwise nothing will happen. For instance, without a draw(), this code will stop after the setup() method.

That's it. You need to wrap your code in draw() function.

Here a nice "button"

```
int radius = 15;
int radius2 = 15;
PGraphics pg ;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500); 
  pg = createGraphics(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(255);
  pg.blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
  pg.fill(255);
  pg.noStroke();
  pg.ellipse(width/2, height/2, radius, radius);
  pg.ellipse(width/2.25, height/2.25, radius2, radius2);
  pg.ellipse(width/2.25, height/1.8, radius2, radius2);
  pg.ellipse(width/1.8, height/2.25, radius2, radius2);
  pg.ellipse(width/1.8, height/1.8, radius2, radius2);
  radius++;
  pg.endDraw();


  background(255);
  image(pg, 0, 0);
}
```